# Go from UITableView cell to a Detail view

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, tableview

I have searched a lot about this topic and I can't get this code work. When I execute it, it only shows my test NSLog but the code to go from one view to another doesn't do anything. Here you have the following code:

//FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "StationDetailsViewController.h"


@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController{
  NSArray *ListaEstaciones;
  NSArray *ListaID;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *ListaEstaciones;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *ListaID;
@end
```

//FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "StationDetailsViewController.h"
@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize ListaEstaciones;
@synthesize ListaID;

//...

- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSLog(@"Pushing...");
StationDetailsViewController *controller = [[StationDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StationDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release], controller = nil; 
}

@end
```

I have tried lots of tutorials and my book but I don't know what is wrong. Thanks a lot, guys.

EDIT: Reading your answers I found that the error is on AppDelegate.m where rootViewController is defined.

//AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I don't know what to edit here to make this:
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
work properly.

Comment: you probably don't have a self.navigationController. Do you have a navigation controller as rootViewController? Start with a navigation based template

Comment: My application is a TabBarController which first tab is the view that I copied here. In AppDelegate.m I have this:         self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is in **[self navigationController]** .. put a break point on this line of code and probaly you will find its value = **nil** cuz of that you are not having your detail controller .. you could solve this like that `UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourMainViewControllerInstance];`

**This The appDelegate Code :**

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIViewController *firstViewController = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FBConFirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *secondViewController = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FBConSecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
 UINavigationController *nav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController]autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav, secondViewController, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Where I have to put this line of code? Inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: No in the class that you present the FirstViewController from.

Comment: Do you mean to write     UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:FirstViewController];
 in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate.m?

Comment: Yes .. Check This i make a sample application for you and test it ,, its work .. your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function should be similar to the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some problem either with datasource and delegate settings or your navigation controller.

Check this tutorial [UITableView Tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/)

This might be helpful to you.

Enjoy Coding :)